# Jekyll on GitHub Pages: include markdown in another markdown file

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages, static-site, kramdown

I'm using `kramdown` with Jekyll on GitHub Pages. I have a piece of markdown that I want to use twice, and don't want to maintain two versions of it. How can I include this in other markdown files?

For example, I want to type something like

```
{: include otherFile.md }
```

and have the contents of `otherFile.md` rendered directly where this command is. Note that the parent file is also a markdown file, and not an HTML template.

Additional consideration: it would be great to be able to do this with the default GitHub pages workflow, and not have to use a plugin that is disabled by GH pages and have to push compiled versions of the site manually.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The way to go seems to be [`include_relative`](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/#including-files-relative-to-another-file). I found this answer by user geraldb on the old [Jekyll forums](http://talk.jekyllrb.com/):

> Yes, there's a simple way. It works "out-of-the-box" in Jekyll (and
>   GitHub Pages). Just tried it. See the Vienna.html test page e.g.:
>
> ```
> ---
> layout: default
> ---
>
> some text here
>
> {% include_relative test_header.md %}
>
> some more text here
>
> {% include_relative test_footer.md %}
> ```
>
> See the source ->
>   [`test.md`](https://github.com/austriacodes/vienna.html/blob/537ff83be9bf396afa19e65e6a7bdbcfdebf9f45/test.md) and the [live page](http://viennahtml.github.io/test).
>
> The "trick" if you want to call it so - is to use `include_relative`
>   if you want to have the building block texts (e.g. `intro.md`,
>   `explanation.md`, `conclusion.md`, etc.) along with your page (in the
>   same folder). Cheers. Happy Jekylling.

---

Since I've first written this answer, the original forum post seems to be completely gone and I haven't found it archived on archive.org. The answer link on the old forum was [this](https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/include-markdown-in-another-markdown/3182) (now points to an unrelated post), and the profile of geraldb in the new forum is [here](https://talk.jekyllrb.com/u/geraldb/summary).

The first link in the quoted answer has been updated to point to the correct file in the repo as it exists today,<sup>1</sup> and the second link is dead but left unchanged as I'm quoting the original author here.

---

<sup>1</sup>Thanks to [Ben Leggiero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3939277/ben-leggiero) for finding it!

Comment: `include_relative` worked for me, too. Although the [example code on the Jekyll tutorial page](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/#including-files-relative-to-another-file) only shows the case for embedding a .html file, it also works for .md files.

Answer (score 20):

For me, the problem couldn't be solved with importing by `include_relative` and using the *normal* `include` does not render the included Markdown files.

But capturing the include and then piping it through `markdownify` is a pretty good workaround:

```
{% capture my_include %}{% include a_markdown_file.md %}{% endcapture %}
{{ my_include | markdownify }}
```

I found this in [GH:/jekyll/jekyll#1303 (comment)](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/1303#issuecomment-21067548). That's a feature request for avoiding the capturing. It's closed, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Ruby gem [markdown_helper](https://rubygems.org/gems/markdown_helper) that supports include files.

Answer (score 0):

I added:

```
---
layout: default
---
```

to the top of the .html file and `{% include my_partial.html %}`  finally worked.